# variable to keep running count in for loop and print a total at the end

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I'm new to scripting and I'm trying to make a script to count files in each folder (and sub-folders) of the current directory.

This script seems to be working OK:

```
for dir in $( ls -pa | grep / | tail -n +3 ); do 
    echo "${dir%/}: $( find ${dir} -type f | wc -l )"
done
```

But, I'd like to print the total number of files after the for loop without inefficiently using the find command to count the total.

I've tried a few things with no success.

```
for dir in $( ls -pa | grep / | tail -n +3 ); do 
     echo "${dir%/}: `count=`$( find ${dir} -type f | wc -l )" 
     total=$((total+count))
done 

echo "total: $total"
```

Not sure if my command substitution is correct and would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction! Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What's wrong with your code is `count` variable is not set correctly.

```
echo "${dir%/}: `count=`$( find ${dir} -type f | wc -l )"
```

In the line, `count=` is command substitution which results in nothing. So `count` won't be set because *there is no assignment statement but a command substitution and another command substitution*.
So here is the solution:

```
for dir in $( ls -pa | grep / | tail -n +3 ); do count=$( find ${dir} -type f | wc -l ); echo "${dir%/}: $count"; total=$((total+count)); done; echo "total: $total"
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been fiddling around on this for over an hour with no success. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of files (with recursivity) in each direct subfolders in the current folder (containing no one file), and compute the total of files without recount all with `find . -type f | wc -l` do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

total=0
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | sed 1d); do
     echo "${dir}/: $(find ${dir} -type f | wc -l)"
     total=$((total + count))
done

echo "total: ${total}"
```

Comment: I believe I am making use of this command already. Thanks though.

Comment: `$( ls -pa | grep / | tail -n +3 )` is strange use `$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d)` ;)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. My knowledge of commands is still very small and that was the only way I could logically find the folders. Thanks !!